# Why is container-fluid working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created an ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2015, I selected the .Net Framework 4.5.2 template so it's using bootstrap 3.0.0

I modified the body div in `_Layout.cshtml` from `<div class="container body-content">` to `<div class="container-fluid body-content">`, it works (the content is using the full width) but how can it be working? `container-fluid` is not picked up by the Visual Studio IntelliSense and indeed the css files don't have `fluid` anywhere in them. What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what CSS files you're looking at, but bootstrap 3 definitely has a `.container-fluid` class:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}
```

Check for yourself (ctrl+f) in the css file from a CDN: https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

And from the [bootstrap 3 CSS grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or **.container-fluid** (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

Edit: I just noticed you said bootstrap 3.0.0, and I just checked that [CSS file](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css) and you're correct. There is no `container-fluid` class defined, so I don't think you are using 3.0.0